# Quill JS - check if text change on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill, textchanged

I am using Quill (Rich Text) and need to find a way to checking to see if the text has changed when the page does a form submit. I am quite new to using Quill and have been looking at the events [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/events.html). Using the text-change triggers everytime the text is changed (obviously) but I have other Form Input controls on the page which are checked on form submit to see if they have changed... I need my RTF boxes to do the same.

EDIT

I have managed to get the Event Firing using the example below. My problem now is that the event appears to trigger even when the editor is pre-populated on page load. I dont want to acknowledge these initial loads, only if the text has been changed by a user.

Comment: Could you please help with below question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135622/quill-editor-check-for-change-in-content-in-angular

Answer (score 5):

Two ways to do so:

1) listen for quill changes and if any occurred, raise a flag telling your form content has changed (flow: if you add a char, then delete it, your flag would be true even if resulting content is the same)

Using :

```
let changes = false
quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
  changes = true
})
```

2) comparing two snapshots of the document to detect front-end if changes occurred. You could either compare strings (with `quill.getText()`) this is the simplest, but you could miss lot of things, I would recommend to compare objects (with `quill.getContents()`) and use lodash or other deep equality objects method check.

Using:

```
const initialContents = quill.getContents()
const beforeSubmitContents = quill.getContents()
const hasChanged = _.isEqual(initialContents.ops, beforeSubmitContents.ops)
```

Comment: Thanks for this...! I am not in work to try it out for a week or so but this seems to make sense. Hopefully will get it implemented and feed back.

Comment: Many thanks for this again! I am just trying to implement now but not sure I am getting this right. I have a javascript method that is called to create some events, I basically want to apply the above to all uses of quill ($j('.ql-editor').on('text-change'....) but I can see the event is being created against the div - but nothing happens when I try triggering the event. I will update my Question with what I am doing.

Comment: I have now successfully applied this and got the event triggering. What i am finding however is that it is getting fired when the text box is first auto-populated with data from "" to "some data". If there is no data on load then the event is not triggered - as expected. Is there an easy way to make sure the event is only triggered when a change is made by the user and not by the field being auto-populated. i have checked the source attribute and this is always showing 'user'.

Comment: I might add that I have several quill text boxes on a page which is why I have gone down the event route.. It seemed easier! I may be missing something from your other suggestion that might help but cannot see that just yet.

Comment: @CJH maybe check the `source` of the event ? on loading, it might originate from `api` while edited by an human it will originate from `user` ?

Comment: They were both coming from User :(

Answer (score 3):

for detect if exis change only implement this function

```
quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
  if (source == 'api') {
    console.log("An API call triggered this change.");
  } else if (source == 'user') {
    console.log("A user action triggered this change.");
  }
});
```

this function detect if write or have a change on editor, detect if has change on your words or font or image...etc.. !!
In this case i use the example of official page:
[page official](https://quilljs.com/playground/#form-submit) 
result :
[image: Result Example]