# use input instead of keydown event in Quill

Tags: angular, quill

I have this [unicode converter](https://github.com/s1n7ax/open-unicode-converter) opensource application in which I'm using Quill. The issue right now is, the [application](https://www.sinhalaunicode.org/) works on PC browser but not on mobile. Reason is `event.key` passes `Unidentified` on mobile.

My attempt was to use catch the `input` event, when the pressed key can be converted, `preventDefault()` and insert the text manually to the editor based on `event.data` property. However, Quill writes the data on to the editor on `keydown` which needs to be stopped.

Current implementation:

```js
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.editorService.onKeyDown.emit(event)
}
```

```js
convert(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (!this.converting) return

    /*
     * keydown event passes keys like backspace as "Backspace" this is to
     * try to eliminate those keys being typed literally on to the editor
     */
    if (event.key.length > 1) return

    event.preventDefault()
    const currentWord = this.editorComponent.getCurrentWord()
    const rule = this.converter.convert(event.key, currentWord)

    this.editorComponent.type(rule.result)
}
```

When I add a new event handler to `input` (to document), Quill already have typed the entered letter since `keydown` is emitted before `input`.

Is it possible to make it use `input` event to write stuff instead?

Comment: Does this [check if text change on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107174/quill-js-check-if-text-change-on-form-submit) answer your question?

Comment: I need it to be realtime. If I press 'a', I need to catch the event, preventDefault() so Quill will not insert 'a' to the editor, and insert 'අ' instead. One of the solutions is `text-change` event which I don't believe have a preventDefault or a way to prevent Quill from inserting the text

Answer (score -1):

Check out also this first [get the keycode and cast it to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436329/11719787) this might help, if not see the below answer.

I am able to prevent `keydown` event (example below)

```js
this.editor = new Quill(editorEle, {
    ...
});

this.editor.root.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
  this.editorService.onKeyPress.emit(evt); //Call your event emitter
  evt.preventDefault(); //prevent further
});
```

You can also add `input` event listener

```js
this.editor.root.addEventListener('input', evt => {
  this.editorService.onKeyPress.emit(evt); //Call your event emitter
});
```

But there is one problem though, quill is creating context and something else on `keydown` event, you will lose all of that if you `preventDefault`

[Check quills `keydown` event](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/541bd363ac8eae2ad876f16a950cea439eae262a/modules/keyboard.js#L112)